# Webservice not working after disabling TLS 1.0 from hosted server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

We are using Webservices(ASP.Net, C#) in a Web application(ASP.Net, C#). The Webservice works like an API to access DataBase. We are hosted the Webservice in one Server and the DataBase is in another server.

As per the updated PCI compliance policy, site should not use TLS 1.0. So, we planned to disabled the TLS 1.0 from server. After disabling this TLS 1.0 the webservice couldn't communicate with DB. We got the below exceptions

- Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
  the operation or the server is not responding
- The ConnectionString    property has not been initialized

**Do we need to do any code changes to make the Webservice works only with TLS 1.1\TLS 1.2?**

So, it would be great, if any one have some suggestions or work around to use webservice after disabling the TLS 1.0

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I got the solution. I have added the below code in web application's [Global.asax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC2yG.png) Application_Start() section like shown in the image.

*Code:*
`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;`

We need to explicitly select the Protocols (TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2).  It resolves my issue that, using secured(HTTPS) webservice in my web application.

Comment: If you don't mind, which version of ASP.NET were you using?

Comment: We tried everything and this was the final solution.  My issue was that our web app worked, but a call to a web service on a different server failed.  We were getting the "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm" error on the web service call.  Added this line above and it now works.  EDIT - running 4.6.1 framework.

Comment: Works for me too, great job.